# Geoserver tiles mismatch

Tags: geoserver, coordinate-system, wms, tiles

I tried to get WMS tiles from geoserver like

*/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/layername@EPSG%3A4326@png/15/19142/9530.png*

or with another projection

*/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/layername@EPSG%3A900913@png/15/19142/9530.png*

But all the time I got empty tile. For grabbing them I use openlayers. 
All in all the tile, which should be in 19142/9530.png are located in:

*geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/layername@EPSG%3A900913@png/15/19801/22523.png*

So as I could understood all the tiles have pretty big offset

[The offset tiles location](http://xmages.net/i/3437112)

and I got them in the center of the map.That layer which should be in Europe

[Where tile are really located](http://xmages.net/i/3437110)

are located in the part of Africa and ocean(link 1).

That's why I  couldn't use them with OSM maps and ect(because my tiles are simply empty).

Can someone help me to manage with this problem? Is this a issue of geowebcache (geoserver) or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: I think we need to see your openlayers code to see what's going on - I don't think it is a GeoServer problem

Comment: Ok, here it is (by the link you can see that two same layers are located in different parts of the world http://goodroads.ru/map/debag ).
           var osm =new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("New Layer", "http://188.138.112.98:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/world%3Aroads@EPSG%3A900913/${z}/${x}/${y}.png", {numZoomLevels: 18});
goodMarkers = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(         "Gradient","http://188.138.112.98:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wms",       {'layers':'world:roads',          transparent: "true",          tiles:"true",              format: "image/png"} );

Comment: If the data comes up off the shore of Nigeria, the data is most probably in lat/lon instead of EPSG:900913.